# How to save/write a file from html with javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser-nativefs

I am doing an easy desktop app to crop photos, in order to do this I have a npm project with a few dependencies and an HTML file and launch the browser with the following command, `chromium-browser --disable-web-security`.

The problem is that when the app execute this code:

```
crop(event) {
        cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob((blob) => {
        saveAs(new Blob([blob] ), './a.jpg');
      });
```

And this download automatically the file in the download folder instead of the same folder where the index file is.

Any idea about how can I set a relative path to download the file?

Thanks.

Comment: JavaScript has no control over where the file is saved. The selects the folder in the file dialog.

Comment: there is not dialog, I am trying to use chrome without security in order to change that preferences.

Comment: If you disable the dialog, it uses the default download folder. There's still no way for JavaScript to set the folder. That would allow web sites to overwrite any of the user's files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just targeting chrome, there is a way. You can use Chrome's FS functionality

https://web.dev/file-system-access/

If you first load the file using this API, you will have the FileHandler object to use when you want to save